# NameError in AttachmentsController#indicateur

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm on Ruby on rails and I started with the library axlsx_rails.

By cons when I get my data from my table to put it in an xlsx file it gives me this error

> undefined local variable or method` attachment 'for # <
>   AttachmentsController: 0x007f7d8ecf1a08> Did you mean? Attachment_url

I attach the files of my program if someone has any idea. Thank you.
[route.rb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTMUb.png)

[view: indicateur.xlsx.axlsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYu70.png)

[controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBF0Q.png)

[view: indicateur.html.erb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajjwX.png)

Comment: Next time please post your code, do not post an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is giving you that error because it is looking for `attachment` method. I believe you want to do is to fecth all the attachments. So instead of you code:

```
@attachments = attachment.all
```

You should upcase the Model:

```
@attachments = Attachment.all
```

Comment: @mor diop I think make a different thread for that. And it seems my answer solved your issue above, so you can accept my answer.

Comment: of course it solved it and thank you for that but I have another problem I have this problem after having to solve the first problem i have this 'To respond to a custom format, register it as a MIME type first: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#restful-downloads. If you meant to respond to a variant like :tablet or :phone, not a custom format, be sure to nest your variant response within a format response: format.html { |html| html.tablet { ... } }' thanks for your help

Comment: You should accept the answer if it solved the issue not just saying thank you or +1 here in the comment.